# Async http call inside kafka stream processor and forward response to next processor

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka stream application (written in java springboot), which has let say 3 processors. In second processor, I want to call a rest api in asynchronous manner and when response comes, I want to forward the response to next processor. I do not want stream thread to block on rest api call and pick up other messages while rest api is being executed. Is there any way to do this?
Sample Example of processor I have

```
public class secondprocessorsupplier implements ProcessorSupplier<IndexedRecord, IndexedRecord> {

    public secondprocessorsupplier() {
    }

    private static final ProcessorName PROCESSOR_NAME = ProcessorName.SECOND_PROCESSOR;

    
    @Override
    public Processor<IndexedRecord, IndexedRecord> get() {
        return new Secondprocessor();
    }

    private class Secondprocessor extends Processor<IndexedRecord, IndexedRecord> {    

        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            this.context=context;
        
        }

        @Override
        public void process(final IndexedRecord keyInput, final IndexedRecord streamMessageInput) {
            final HttpClient httpclient= HttpClient.newBuilder()
                  .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30000))
                  .version(getClientVersion(httpClientVersion))
                  .followRedirects(behavior.getHttpClientRedirect())
                  .sslContext(sslContext)
                  .sslParameters(sslParameters)
                  .build());
            httpclient.sendAsync(httprequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).thenAccept(
                response -> context.forward(keyInput, response)
            )
        }

        @Override
        public ProcessorName getProcessorName() {
            return PROCESSOR_NAME;
        }

    }
}
```

In above example, in thenAccept execution current node in context is null and forward does not work